# How to Resolve the CkEditor CurlyBraces?

Tags: ckeditor

I am new to the CKEditor. In My Project I have an issue related to Curly Braces.

My Problem is when i enter the code for the curly braces in the source window like below; **Code View**:

```html
<h1>Normal code for curly braces</h1>
{Normal Code}
<h1>Hard code for curly braces</h1>
&#123;Hard code&#125;
```

When I click again source ("WYSIWYG" Editor View) It is getting as follows; **Editor View**:

```html
Normal code for curly braces
{Normal Code}
Hard code for curly braces
{Hard code}
```

When i click again source; **Code View**:

```html
<h1>Normal code for curly braces</h1>
<p>{Normal Code}</p>
<h1>Hard code for curly braces</h1>
<p>{Hard code}</p>
```

But what i want is if i write curly brackets it should display curly brackets if i write code it should display code in code view. It does not convert all the Curly Brackets into code - like what I wrote initially.

In which file I have to configure this related code to get the required output I am not getting. Please help me if any one expertize in CkEditor.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It really sounds like this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you really trying to do? Are the curly things placeholders for other code?

Comment: Is there any way to tell the editor to just leave all code as it is entered and don't attempt to convert into valid html entities?

Comment: Actually for open curly brace the html entity code is &#123; and for close &#125;.Basically when we put code into the editor, we want it to remain exactly as we have entered it.

Comment: Yeah I don't really think that will be the easiest thing to do. But my point is: **Why** do you want to do it? It really looks like you want to do a placeholder, which can be done a lot easier than this using another method.

Comment: In my project there is a requirement that to design a "Fill in the blanks" questions.There is a functionality that if i place a curly braces open and close then it has converted to blank in the place of curly braces.Example is "Question(At Instructor jsp page):India got independence in{1947}".when i click the jsp save button it is converted into as like:"India got independece in_________________".

Comment: But my problem is if there is a polynomial equation that instructor wants to give as question.then all the curly braces converting into blanks Example is:"Question(At Instructor Side)x+{y+z}={x} it is converted into x+________=____but i don not want all the curly braces converted into blanks only in the place of curly braces after equals sign.(Is it possible to resolve the problem by using CkEditor Configuration or anything else)

Comment: How does that problem lead to the one you asked, isn't it totally a different situation? Why won't `<p>Question(At Instructor Side)x+(y+z)={x}</p>` work for you directly like that? If the one before the equals sign should not be converted... instruct the person making the question not to use curly braces. Or use double curly braces as the delimiters like: `<p>Question(At Instructor jsp page):India got independence in{{1947}}</p>`. Or triple. Who does the questions anyway? If I was you, I would create a widget plugin for the placeholders - so much nicer to edit and post-process.

Comment: I really don't understand the reason behind wanting code like `<h1>Normal code for curly braces</h1>{Normal Code}`.

Comment: Hard code and normal code are sample text which i have placed.Actual intention is about curly braces.I have placed &#123;&#125; i am getting curly braces in editor view,after again going back to code view (&#123;&#125;)these things are replaced with '{' '}' but i want them to be as it is.should not be replaced

Comment: OOOOH Now I see, so the additional `<p></p>` tags that appear are not an issue? I misunderstood the question, my apologies. Still I think that a redesign of the feature might be the best solution ;). Maybe someone might have a good solution, but this seems a little complicated. Good luck!

Comment: If you know at least tell me Is there any way to tell the editor to just leave all code as it is entered and don't attempt to convert into valid html entities? in CKEditor.Thanks a lot  Nenotlep.Great help from you

Comment: I am sorry; I don't. I hope someone else might know and answer this question.